# Replace variable in included file with php code without eval

Tags: php, model-view-controller, frameworks, include

I'm working on my own simple PHP MVC framework I'll be using in a couple of projects. I'm not looking to reinvent the wheel, however frameworks like CakePHP are a bit too large and advanced for what I need.

I have three files, they look like this (simplified):

**indexview.php**

```
<?php
class View {
    public $title = '';
    public $scripts = '';
    public $contents = '';

    public function output() {
        $this->contents = file_get_contents('index.php');
        include 'layout.php';
    }
}
```

**layout.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title><?php echo $this->title; ?></title>
        <?php echo $this->scripts; ?>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php echo $this->contents; ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

**index.php**

```
<h1>Hello world!</h2>
<?php echo 'How are you?'; ?>
```

I know this code isn't correct but it demonstrates what I need. I want `file1.php` to include `file2.php`, where the `$this->contents` variable is replaced with the contents of `file3.php`. In its current state it works, but the php code of `file3.php` is displayed, and not executed.

I would prefer to accomplish this without using eval. Also, I'd like to use PHP's variable system (in that I can use `$this->contents` instead of having to replace specific strings - so no Smarty-ish stuff).

I know it should be possible since CakePHP uses a similar system (you can use `$this->fetch('content')` for example, and it will replace it with the content of that page, which could possibly contain PHP code).

Thanks!

Comment: you need to change your third file just like file one and then include both file in second one create object and then use them .

Comment: @anantkumarsingh yes but that would cause me to have to rely on includes and paths in the third file - I'd prefer to use PHP's variables, since they allow for more flexability.